# Process the body of 403 Forbidden with twisted.web.client

Tags: python, twisted

I have the general code:

```
client.getPage(url, headers=headers).addCallback(...).addErrback(errorHandler)
```

with the following error handler:

```
def errorHandler(self, error):
    log.critical('Error: ', extra=dict(error=error))
```

All that I can get from such processing is the following:

```
Error: {'error': <twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.web.error.Error: 403 Forbidden>}
```

Problem is that I need to process the body of the error response **(yep, that's AWS)**, but there's no API in twisted.web.error.Error to do it, and I couldn't find any examples on the Internet.

General example contains this:

```
def errorHandler(self, error):
    # release memory and handlers 
    print(error)
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Twisted docs, I think you should be able to do this:

```py
def errorHandler(self, error):
    # `error` is a twisted.python.failure.Failure
    original_exc = error.value
    # `original_exc` is a twisted.web.error.Error
    response_body = original_exc.response
    log.critical('Error: %s', response.body, extra=dict(error=error))
```

- https://docs.twisted.org/en/stable/api/twisted.python.failure.Failure.html
- https://docs.twisted.org/en/stable/api/twisted.web.error.Error.html

Comment: Thanks! You solved my problem :) Checked, working.